# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, spring, maven, gradle

i'm trying to include to my Android Studio project two Spring library:

```
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:2.0.0.M2'   
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M2'
```

Gradle build returns me these stacktrace error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I know that Gradle doesn't like too many packages included to projects, but I need them all to correctly run my android application.

Comment: Can you please post your `build.gradle`? Also, do you have `*.jars` in your libs folder?

Comment: problem solved, it seems  problem was caused by a conflict with log4j compiled by gradle too. I removed it cause i didn't really need that library. another question, there are some ways to avoid use of "exclude 'META-INF/something' " in Gradle packagingOptions?

Comment: You have to use `packagingOptions` if two libraries have conflicting files. Post your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, it seems problem was caused by a conflict with log4j compiled by gradle too. I removed it cause i didn't really need that library.